# Persist create new entity while already exists (Ont-To-Many Many-To-One relation)

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an Angular4 app working with Symfony3/Doctrine2 Rest Api.

Both in Angular and Symfony, I have those entities :

- Table
- TableNode
- Node

The relation between Table and Node is :

Table (OneToMany) TableNode (ManyToOne) Node

What is a "ManyToMany" relation with attributes.

In the Angular app, I create a new Table (form a TableModel that has exactly the same properties that the Table entity in the Symfony app).
This Table contains several Node entities that come from the Api (so they already exists in my database).

What I want is to create a new Table that contains new TableNode entities and each TableNode should contain existing Node entities.

When I want to save my table within the db, I call my Api through a Put action :

```
/**
 * PUT Route annotation
 * @Put("/tables")
 */
public function putTableAction(Request $request)
{
    $em         = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('psi_db');
    $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
    $dataJson   = $request->query->get('table');
    $table      = $serializer->deserialize($dataJson, Table::class, 'json');

    // Here, my $table has no id (that's ok), the TableNode subentity has no id (ok) and my Node subentity already have an id (because they come from the db)

    $em->persist($table);

    // Here, my $table has a new id (ok), my TableNode has a new id (ok) BUT my Node subentity have a NEW id, so it will be duplicated 

    $em->flush();

    $view = $this->view();
    $view->setData($table);
    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

I tried to use $em->merge($table) instead of $em->persist($table) and my node subentities keep there own id (so they may not be duplicated within the flush) BUT the table and tableNode have no id (null) and are not persisted.

The only solution I found is to loop through the TableNode entities, retrieve the Node entity from the database and do a tableNode->setNode :

```
$tns = $table->getTableNodes();
foreach ($tns as $tn) {
    $nodeId = $tn->getNode()->getId();
    $dbNode = $nodeRepo->find($nodeId);
    $tn->setNode($dbNode);
}
```

But it's not a good solution because I make a db search within a loop and a table could contains more than a hundred of TableNode/Node so it might take a lot of resources.

Does anyone have a cleaner solution ?
Thanks.

edit : add classes

**Table :**

```
/**
 * Table_
 * Doctrine "Table" is a reserved name, so we call it Table_
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="psi_table")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Table_Repository")
 *
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Table_
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tNodes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @Expose
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Expose
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \stdClass
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="object", nullable=true)
     *
     * @Expose
     */
    private $author;

    /**
    * @var \stdClass
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TableNode", mappedBy="table", cascade={"persist"})
    *
    * @Expose
    * @Type("ArrayCollection<AppBundle\Entity\TableNode>")
    * @SerializedName("tNodes")
    */
    private $tNodes;
}
```

**TableNode :**

```
/**
 * TableNode
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="psi_table_node")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TableNodeRepository")
 *
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class TableNode
{
    public function __construct($table = null, $node = null, $position = null)
    {
        if($table) $this->table = $table;
        if($node) $this->node = $node;
        if($position) $this->position = $position;
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @Expose
     */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
     *
     * @Expose
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="groupSocio", type="string", nullable=true)
     *
     * @Expose
     * @SerializedName("groupSocio")
     */
    private $groupSocio;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Table_", inversedBy="tNodes", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    *
    * @Expose
    * @Type("AppBundle\Entity\Table_")
    */
    private $table;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Node", inversedBy="tables", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    *
    * @Expose
    * @Type("AppBundle\Entity\Node")
    */
    private $node;
}
```

**Node :**

```
/**
 * TableNode
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="psi_table_node")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TableNodeRepository")
 *
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class TableNode
{
    public function __construct($table = null, $node = null, $position = null)
    {
        if($table) $this->table = $table;
        if($node) $this->node = $node;
        if($position) $this->position = $position;
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @Expose
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
     *
     * @Expose
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="groupSocio", type="string", nullable=true)
     *
     * @Expose
     * @SerializedName("groupSocio")
     */
    private $groupSocio;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Table_", inversedBy="tNodes", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    *
    * @Expose
    * @Type("AppBundle\Entity\Table_")
    */
    private $table;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Node", inversedBy="tables", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    *
    * @Expose
    * @Type("AppBundle\Entity\Node")
    */
    private $node;
}
```

**Submitted data (example) :**

```
{"tNodes":[{"id":0,"position":0,"groupSocio":"group1","node":{"id":683,"frontId":"1502726228584","level":"synusy","repository":"baseveg","name":"A synusy from my Angular app!","geoJson":{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":[],"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-10.0634765625,42.0982224112]}}]},"lft":1,"lvl":0,"rgt":2,"children":[{"id":684,"frontId":"1502726228586","level":"idiotaxon","repository":"baseflor","name":"poa annua","coef":"1","geoJson":{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":[],"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-10.0634765625,42.0982224112]}}]},"lft":1,"lvl":0,"rgt":2,"validations":[{"id":171,"repository":"baseflor","repositoryIdTaxo":"7075","repositoryIdNomen":"50284","inputName":"poa annua","validatedName":"Poa annua L."}]}],"validations":[]}}]}
```

Comment: Please, show us JMSSerializer annotations in class Table, TableNode and Node.
Also show example of  Request URL you submit (or value of $dataJson)

Comment: I edited the post and add asked informations. Thx

Comment: You have a typo - you added TableNode twice, and didn't add Node class.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose putTableAction is to:

- create new instances of **Table_**
- create new instance of **TableNode**
- do nothing with **Node**

It means that:

1.You do not need to submit any details of Node. **Id** field is enough:

```
{"tNodes":[{"id":0,"position":0,"groupSocio":"group1","nodeId": 683}]}
```

2.You can add one more field to **TableNode**, called **$nodeId**, and map it with "node" field in DB. The purpose of this field is to simplify deserialization, in all other places you can use **$node** field.

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="node", type="integer")
 *
 * @Expose
 */
private $nodeId;
```